# Continue running NUnit after failures

Tags: nunit, continuous-integration, teamcity, nunit-console

I am running nunit-console from a CI configured in TeamCity to run tests from various assemblies. Once one of the TestFixtures has a failing test, then the test execution will stop.

Currently i am able to see the first tests that failed, but am unaware if there are more testfixtures that might fail down the line.

I would like to get a summary that lists the failing tests and test fixtures, without all the details of the exceptions thrown.

Anyone have any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i am using a final builder script that runs MSBuild

Comment: Cool, and finally, are you using NUnit MSBuild Community task to run unit tests or just manually executing nunit-console executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NUnit should run all of the unit tests in the specified assembly, regardless of the number of test failures.  The first thing I would check is the raw xml output from the unit test run.  You may find that the tests are being executed, but the build server is failing to display all of the results.  If that is the case, there may be a faulty xslt that needs to be modified.

Another thing to try is running all of the tests on your box using the command-line tool, and see if it runs all of the tests.  If they run on your box but not the server, you may have a configuration problem on the build box.

Yet another possibility is that the failure is a critical one (failure to load an assembly perhaps) which is causing NUnit itself to error out.